# Blazor Extensions cannot be installed

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I have VS 2019 16.1.3 and .Net Core 3 SDK preview 6 installed on my Win 10 machine and when I tried to Install Blazor Extensions It fails and this exception is thrown :

Note :(It used to work before I update the VS 2019 to 16.1.3 and .Net core 3 SDK to preview 6)

```
6/16/2019 12:55:28 AM - Searching for applicable products...
6/16/2019 12:55:28 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
6/16/2019 12:55:28 AM - Found installed product - ssms
6/16/2019 12:55:28 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
6/16/2019 12:55:29 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if this is now enforced via the error you’re seeing, but you need to be using the latest preview of Visual Studio not the GA version.

The current preview version is 16.2 Preview 2